How to get_previous_ti in airflow?
I'm calling this in my operator:
current_ti = context['ti']
previous_ti = current_ti.get_previous_ti()

but it fails with
    previous_ti = current_ti.get_previous_ti()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 79, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1846, in get_previous_ti
    return _get_previous_ti(task_instance=self, state=state, session=session)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1175, in _get_previous_ti
    dagrun = task_instance.get_previous_dagrun(state, session=session)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1832, in get_previous_dagrun
    return _get_previous_dagrun(task_instance=self, state=state, session=session)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 940, in _get_previous_dagrun
    dag = task_instance.task.dag

